# How do I open a JSFL file without running it?

Tags: flash, jsfl

When I open a jsfl file from Flash's file menu, it opens the code as a document that I can edit. But when I try to open a jsfl file from explorer and I specify Flash as the program I want to open it with, Flash just runs the jsfl code instead of opening it for editing. How do I open a jsfl file for editing from the file's location?

I'm using Flash CS4 and Windows 8.1

Answer (score -1):

For Windows, use "CTRL + O" to open JSFL files.